# Conky colors wont show up

Tags: gnome, configuration, conky

I am running Gnome 3 and am trying to get conky to work. When I just installed and ran `conky` in terminal, this showed up.

[image: conky-screenshot]

So I googled how to make it look better and I found Conky Colors. I followed this [guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/conky-colors-makes-your-conky-beautiful.html)
and when I ran it, nothing showed up on the screen but *conky* shows up in the system monitor.

I used this configuration before I installed it

```
./conky-colors --cairo --theme=elementary --cpu=2 --swap --clock=cairo
```

Can someone please help me either make it show up again or configure it?

*Note: I'm installing conky because screenlets just doesn't look as good as conky colors.*

Comment: actually i ran conky -c ~/.conkycolors/conkyrc

Comment: The screenshot you posted, in the terminal, you have the error "invalid configuration file 'home/carlos/conkycolors/conkyrc'" so either the file does not exist or there is a syntax problem. Pastebin the contents of the file.

Comment: oh! the setup said Congratulations, your configuration is saved bu t when I navigated to it, there was no file! I never would have seen that. Thanks!

Comment: can you post your conky script?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by re-creating the `/home/carlos/.conkycolors/conkyrc` configuration file (which was missing for some reason).

See screenshot in question, and bodhi.zazen and ccrama's comments, for details.